# Flash as3 platform game Error 1009

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im making a platform game with patrolling enemies with an enemy class and a bumper class which changes the direction of the enemies when they collide. Once you open the door and call on the nextLevel function I need the enemies and bumpers to be removed. This is the code for the nextLevel function:

```
function nextLevel():void {
    currentLevel++;
    trace("Next Level: " + currentLevel);
    if (enemyList.length>0) {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < enemyList.length; i++) {
            trace("enemyRemoved");
            enemyList[i].removeSelf();
        }
    }
    if (bumperList.length>0) {
        for (var b:int = 0; b < bumperList.length; b++) {
            trace("bumperRemoved");
            bumperList[b].removeSelf();
        }
    }
    if (currentLevel==2) {
        gotoLevel2();
        addEnemiesToLevel2();
        addBumpersToLevel2();
    }
}
if (currentLevel==3) {
    gotoLevel3();
    addEnemiesToLevel3();
    addBumpersToLevel3();
    trace("gotoLevel3");
}
```

which works fine for going to level 2. But somehow when I go to level 3, I get  error 1009 cannot access a property of a null object reference when removing the bumpers. I don't understand why it would work for level 2 but not 3 and also the enemies get removed just fine which is almost identical to the remove bumper code. Here is my removeSelf function in the bumper class

```
public function removeSelf():void {
            trace("remove bumper");
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bumperloop);
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
```

Also my function for pressing the down arrow key while on the open door to call the nextLevel function

```
} else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
        downPressed=true;
        if (doorOpen&&player.hitTestObject(back.other.lockedDoor)) {
            nextLevel();
        }
```

Anyone know what could be the problem here? I would be very grateful to anyone who could answer Iv'e been working at this for days. It gives me an error on the bumperList[b].removeSelf(); line on the nextLevel function and this.parent.removeChild(this); in the bumper class and on the nextLevel(); line in my keydown code

Comment: Could specify what line the error is occuring on?  Also, could it be that your `if (currentLevel==3) {` section is not inside your `nextLevel()` function?

Comment: Have you cleared array of enemy list and bumper list after removing all child

Comment: why would you not post the full error?

Comment: no i haven't cleared the array of bumperlist and enemylist how would i do that? also I added the lines it says theres an error on